# nodemon show error for es16

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodemon

I have `Ubuntu 16.10` and `node.js 7`

```
nodejs -v
v7.6.0
```

I have installed `sudo npm install supervisor -g` for auto-reload `node.js`. But if I write for example arrow function then I see error:

```
user@user-pc:~/dev/a$ nodemon  app.js
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
/home/user/dev/a/app.js:11
app.get('/rtc', (req, res)=>{
                          ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

If i run my app simple `nodejs app.js` then all is finely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that nodejs is using ES6/E2015 and nodemon not.
Combining the hint from the [babel-installation](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server#watching-file-changes-with-nodemon) I propose a `nodemon --exec nodejs` for a trial...

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon uses **node** exec.

> Remember that nodemon is a replacement wrapper for node, think of it as replacing the word "node" on the command line when you run your script.

You need to use **node** not **nodejs**.

Create symbolic link for node

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: That's too dangerous, changing/overwriting the link. There might be side effects.

Comment: It's safe if you don't have **node** in your system.

Comment: But in this case, maybe @alex10 has two nodes installed.